# Eclipse RCP IJob: Limit numer of concurrent executing jobs

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

How can I tell Eclipse RCP Job management to run at most x jobs at the same time?

EDIT:

It works by using a custom scheduling rule as described in the answer.

Its important to never pass the same rule reference to more than one job.

Here is the class I use:

public class JobMaster {

```
private class Listener implements IJobChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void aboutToRun(final IJobChangeEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void awake(final IJobChangeEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void done(final IJobChangeEvent event) {
        synchronized (JobMaster.this) {
            running--;
            System.err.println("now running " + running);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void running(final IJobChangeEvent event) {
        synchronized (JobMaster.this) {
            running++;
            System.err.println("now running " + running);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduled(final IJobChangeEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sleeping(final IJobChangeEvent event) {
    }

}

private class MyRule implements ISchedulingRule {

    public MyRule() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(final ISchedulingRule rule) {
        if (rule == this) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConflicting(final ISchedulingRule rule) {
        synchronized (JobMaster.this) {
            if (rule == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (rule instanceof MyRule) {
                return running >= maxRun;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private final Listener l = new Listener();

private final int maxRun;

private volatile int running = 0;

public JobMaster(final int maxRun) {
    this.maxRun = maxRun;

}

public synchronized void add(final Job j) {
    j.setRule(new MyRule());
    j.addJobChangeListener(l);
    j.schedule();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Job Manager does not have a way to limit the overall number of jobs.

For Jobs that you are creating you could create an `ISchedulingRule` rule which limited the number of your jobs that run at the same time. Call `Job.setRule(rule)` to set the rule on the job (do this before scheduling the job).

An example scheduling rule (from Java Debug):

```
class SerialPerObjectRule implements ISchedulingRule {

  private Object fObject = null;

  public SerialPerObjectRule(Object lock) {
     fObject = lock;
  }

  public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
    return rule == this;
  }

  public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {

    if (rule instanceof SerialPerObjectRule) {
      SerialPerObjectRule vup = (SerialPerObjectRule)rule;
      return fObject == vup.fObject;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

This stops more than one job that uses a particular object from running at a time.

Update:

The job manager checks the following conditions on a scheduling rule:

```
// contains method must be reflexive
Assert.isLegal(rule.contains(rule));

// contains method must return false when given an unknown rule
Assert.isLegal(!rule.contains(nullRule));

// isConflicting method must be reflexive
Assert.isLegal(rule.isConflicting(rule));

// isConflicting method must return false when given an unknown rule
Assert.isLegal(!rule.isConflicting(nullRule));
```

Comment: I already tried using a SchedulingRule. Unfortunately this does not work:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.validateRule(JobManager.java:1573)

Assert.isLegal(rule.isConflicting(rule));

Comment: That is telling you the logic of your rule is incorrect. The rule must be 'reflexive' - `isConflicting` with the same rule passed as the parameter must return true. Added the requirements to the answer

Comment: See answer about JobGroup as the supported way of implementing throttling/limiting.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Eclipse Mars (4.5), one can use job groups to limit the number of concurrent threads:

```
JobGroup jobGroup = new JobGroup("Job...", /* maxThreads*/ 10, /* seedJobsCount */ 100);

for (int ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++)
{            
    Job job = new Job("job name")
    {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
        {
            // do something
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.setJobGroup(jobGroup);
    job.schedule();
}

jobGroup.join(10000, monitor);
```